# How to define a var in jQuery that works for multiple click() functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, global-variables

I defined an array in jQuery from which I want randomly select an item and display it on the website but also give the option to tweet this exact item. Have a look at my code which I defined within the `<script> ... </script>` element.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#click").click(function() {
            var quotPick = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random()*quotes.length)];
            $("#text").text(quotPick);
        });
        $("#tweet").click(function() {
            var quotPick = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random()*quotes.length)];
            window.open('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?hashtags= cali, hank&text=' + quotPick);
        }); 
    });
```

If I write the code like that the `quotPick` variable will always be differently tweeded than displayed. If I define it outside the `$(#click)...` or even before the `$(document).ready ...` I will only be able to click at the button once to generate an item selection.

Where or how do I have to define the `quotPick` so that my code works? Where was I making wrong assumptions? Thanks in advance, guys!

P.S. I tried the `onclick()` function for the button as well but didn't find a satisfying solution either.

Comment: Don't generate a new random quote in the tweeting function.

Comment: Thanks @jjj, that was it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could try something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var quotPick;
    $("#click").click(function() {
        quotPick = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random()*quotes.length)];
        $("#text").text(quotPick);
    });
    $("#tweet").click(function() {
        window.open('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?hashtags= cali, hank&text=' + quotPick);
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Sure, but the extra variable is a bit redundant.

Comment: I totally agree, however in the question he states: "If I define [quotPick] outside the $(#click)... or even before the $(document).ready ... I will only be able to click at the button once to generate an item selection." so I simply presented it in a way that should work, despite having a redundant variable.

Comment: I think you should avoid using extra variable as without that also code will work fine.

Comment: Thank you @Jermaya . That did the job!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
<script>
var quotPick;  //Define it in the beginning of script. This will help you in using the same variable globally  

<!--Other Code here can also use the same value-->

 $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#click").click(function() {
        quotPick = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random()*quotes.length)];
        $("#text").text(quotPick);
    });
    $("#tweet").click(function() {            
        window.open('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?hashtags= cali, hank&text=' + quotPick);
    }); 
});
</script>
```

This should work for you

Answer (score 0):

```
let quotes = ["ds","sd"]
let quotPick;
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#click").click(function() {
            quotPick = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random()*quotes.length)];
            $("#text").text(quotPick);
        });
        $("#tweet").click(function() {

            window.open('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?hashtags= cali, hank&text=' + quotPick);
        }); 
    });
```